# Symfony/Routing: Using POST to Avoid Query Params in URL

Tags: url, parameters, symfony1, routes, http-headers

I want to pass the id from one action to the next action, but I do not want it seen in the URL. Is there a way to hide it?

Using Symfony, I have created a sign-up done page whose URL should be `/signup/done`
When the form is processed, I want to redirect to the `signupSuccess` action and pass the recently created `ID` for future use. So I use...

```
$this->redirect('@signup_done?id=' . $sign_up->getId());
```

The routing is as follows:

```
signup_done:
  url:   /signup/done
  param: { module: SignUp, action: signupDone }
```

I have avoided the :id at the end because I don't want it in the URL. 
But the resulting URL is `/signup/done?id=1`

Just as an experiment, I tried putting this on a template.

```
<?php echo link_to('Sign-up again', '@signup_done?id=1', 'post=true') ?>
```

Even when using post, the query parameter appears in the URL.

The need is: I want to pass the id from one action to the next action, but I do not want it seen in the URL. Is there a way to hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set the id as a parameter in the request using `$request->setParameter('id', $id)` and it was available in the next action.

This kept the URL clean.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post, you need a form. Back in symfony 1.2 there were helpers that you could call and made you just that - but they were removed for the promotion of promoting good code.

Depending on how you want the 'Sign up again' text to look, you can either create a simple form and a submit button, or create a link, attach a click listener, and create a form there via JS, finally post it.

Any parameter that you pass to the route in `url_for`, `link_to` and such end up in the get parameters.

Comment: but the post=true attrib that I mentioned with the link_to does trigger a form submit via JS. Just that the hyperlink appears to have the query-param, and so does the URL of the page. Am I going wrong with my routing definition?